# AWS CI/CD processes against different projects in same Github repo

Tags: aws-lambda, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to figure out how to implement AWS CI/CD.  My objective is to check code into GitHub causing a webhook trigger kicking off a process in AWS for building & deploying my code.  I've been reading about this and am now trying to implement it.

Here is my .Net Core Solution structure:

[image]

The bottom 3 projects in my solution are lambda projects.  I'd like for each of these to have their own CI/CD process.

I'm suspecting since these 3 projects belong to same GitHub repository that I cannot have 3 separate CI/CD processes.  Do I need to break these 3 projects into their own GitHub repo?  Is it possible to connect AWS CodeBuild/Deploy process to a subfolder within a GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done while keeping them in the same repository. You'll have to create 3 different CodeBuild projects. The project configurations will be identical except for 2 things:

- In the source section of each project there's an option under `Start a build under these conditions` called `FILE_PATH`. Set the path of your C# project there so that only code pushed in that project triggers a build.
- In the buildspec section of each project, change the `Buildspec name` to match the relative path from the root of the repo. (For example: `RoiCalculator.Serverless.Api/buildspec.yml`)

Comment: Is it possible for each CodeBuild projects to also be part of a CodePipeline?

Comment: It is possible but builds will be triggered by CodePipeline and not the source settings mentioned in then answer. Source options in CodePipeline are more barebone and I don't think you can apply the same sort of filtering.

Comment: ahh, ok, this is making more sense.  so, I will need to abandon CodePipeline because I'm using a mono-repository with multiple serverless functions therein.